# How to click Save button on a web form using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on automating a task. I want to click a `Save` button on a web form using VBA, but it's not working:

```htm
<input name="save" title="Save" class="btn" type="submit" value=" Save ">
<input name="save" tabindex="79" title="Save" class="btn" type="submit" value=" Save ">
```

I've tried `ie.Document.all("save").Click`, but it doesn't seem to work. What method do I need to click the button?

Comment: I think you may need to share more code than that. Which web page and what does not working mean? Error messages?

Comment: Some discussion that might be similar here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/709346-clicking-button-via-ie-automation-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try going through all your "btn" class collection, and click the one with your `save` value:

```
Dim btnClassColl As Object, btn As Object
Set btnClassColl = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn")

For Each btn In btnClassColl
    If btn.Value Like "*save*" Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

> **Also:** make sure that your web page has FULLY loaded before trying to automate anything.

---

#### Edit

> In response to the comment:
>
> > *This code is neither giving error nor its clicking on btn. Can this be because there are two buttons on web page with same name and function?*

An alternative solution would be that if you **know** the index number of the collection item, you can simply use that index number and not loop at all. In this case, your index # is `1` (remember: `Base 0`).

Try this alternative:

```
Dim btn As Object
ie.document.getElementsByName("save")(1) '1 actually means #2 in index
```

Comment: Hi K.Davis, Thank you for your reply. This code is neither giving error nor its clicking on btn. Can this be because there are two buttons on web page with same name and function?